# creating an access database, what are the primary rules?

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a database like

```
Customer_ID    Customer_Lastname       Customer_Name       Customer_Address
```

Should I store all these infos in just one table or should I make tables like

```
Customer_ID   Customer_Lastname Customer_Name
```

and

```
Customer_ID   Customer Address ?
```

regards

---

Let me detail it more.. I want the app get results as fast as possible. Having 100 tables wont slowdown the app ? Or having only the neccessary info in a table makes it faster ?

I have around 30.000 ID and each has almost 30 different data such as add, name, products they use and their CR managers etc.

Regards

Comment: Will you ever have more than one address for a customer? Or will you every save an old address when you replace it with a new address?

Comment: if customers have a lot of address, you can do it that second one. So you can pull customer's all address. But they have got an address, you can do first one.

Comment: well I will. But am planning to store another address as a new column. Like Work add, home add, branch add, etc.

Comment: thanks DOK (also for editing the post) and Ghost Developer, guess I will do the second.

Comment: That is in almost all cases a bad design choice. For example a question like 'what customer has address abc' becomes hard to answer. Also it will duplicate lots of addresses over columns (when customer works from home). You should buy/read a good book about datamodelling. It will save you lots of time lateron

Comment: A extra column or two for address type and address status should be enough, rather than extra address columns.

Comment: Let me detail it more.. I want the app get results as fast as possible. Having 100 tables wont slowdown the app ? Or having only the neccessary info in a table makes it faster ? I have around 30.000 ID and each has almost 30 different data such as add, name, products they use and their CR managers etc. Regards

Comment: 30.000 entries is tiny for a database - don't worry about performance too much. Proper design will make your life much easier in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Use just one table.

There is no motivation to split it based on your question and my experience.

There *is* motivation to leave it in one... simpler queries and less I/O to retrieve data.

#### Edit:

Later comments reveal that you want customers to have *multiple* addresses. In that case, a second table would be warranted:

```
Table address:
address_id, customer_id (FK), address_name, <address fields as you need>
```

`address_name` would be the nickname, eg "Home", "Office", "Aunt Jenny" or whatever as named by the user.

Comment: In the commments he reveals he wants to create a 1-n relation between customers and addresses (different type of addresses). And are you sure about the less I/O? I would expect that depends on how often you need those address values. If most queries only need the id/name the smaller table would lead to less I/O (I/O is probably not that relevant in this case but asking out of curiosity )

Comment: @Eddy Oh. In that case, split it

Answer (score 0):

I say one table for now but don't use just Customer_Address. Break address up into separate fields:

Address1
Address2
City
State
ZipCode

Comment: It would probably be useful to include an AddressType field as well with options such as Postal, Residential etc